# How do I fix: No view found for id 0x7f0d00aa?

Tags: java, android

I've seen people with the same issue and they said that there is something wrong with the .replace() and the way I've constructed the way the fragment and container are written using the: fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.container, new Fragment()).commit(); 
And that I must do it some other way, which I implemented into my code but I still got the Error.
ERROR:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: mcshreker.pocketmath, PID: 3215
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00aa (mcshreker.pocketmath:id/content_main_container) for fragment secondFragment{bf0f022 #0 id=0x7f0d00aa}
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1292)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Code (Main Activity)

```
package mcshreker.pocketmath;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new firstFragment()).commit();

        // Handle the camera action

}

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new secondFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new thirdFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_fourth_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new fourthFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_fifth_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new fifthFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_sixth_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new sixthFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_seventh_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new seventhFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_eighth_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new eighthFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_ninth_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace
                (R.id.content_main_container, new ninthFragment()).commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

HERE is my content_main_container XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="mcshreker.pocketmath.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/e"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription=""
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/welcome"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Activity_main XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you share your `xml`? Are you sure the element `content_main_container` is a child in your `activity_main`?

Comment: I've shared both XML files, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
No view found for id 0x7f0d00aa (mcshreker.pocketmath:id/content_main_container)
```

check if **content_main_container** is defined in your `activity_main` layout

Comment: Except my content_main_container doesn't lie within my activity_main, they are two different XML files.

Comment: You need to put this layout (container) in the activity layout. The fragment will be placed in this container.

Comment: Ok so this removed the error (thank you), but now when I click on one of the fragments, the window (fragment layout) doesn't load and so I'm stuck on the same window every time. To add on that, there is also a bunch of lag. I don't worry about the lag as much as the loading of the fragments.

Comment: @CodeLife please consider asking a new question explaining your new problem, remember also to include as much details as possible ;)